# (PHP SQL) using SQL data across PHP-powered site

Tags: php, sql

Coming directly from iOS development in Swift I recently started to work with PHP. I'm making a small PHP powered website with a simple userlogin and some features for registered users.

However, I have a general question regarding the data I pull from the SQL database.

In Swift, I took the data and stored it in variables that I could use through the entire app.

What is the "correct" way of doing so in PHP? As of now, I connect to the SQL database when the user log into the site. I then connect again to retrieve some user data. And then again on another section of the site where I need to update the SQL database for the specific user.

It seems like a hell of a lot of SQL requests (UPDATE, INSERT, SELECT) if the site had say 500 users?

So I thought - there must be an easier way.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can cache permanent data (e.g. session data) using something like memcached or redis, so that it will be quickly available on each request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need a variable available at all times?
$_SESSION 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
or
$_COOKIES
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php